# Cover screen part

Tags: android, user-interface, android-fragments, android-activity

## EDIT: no 3rd party libraries please

I want to achieve the following effect, but I am struggling to design a generic solution for devices with different screen sizes.

A common effect used in tutorials. This example was taken from the PlayStation Android application (*notice the transparent circle in the avatar*):

[image: Effect image]

How would you approach this? Is there any tool available is the OS that allows to do so?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi are you looking something like this https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView

Answer (score 0):

For example. You need to create your own custom overlay view for this.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private ImageView mOverLayImage;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Dialog overlayInfo = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
    overlayInfo.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    overlayInfo.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    overlayInfo.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
    overlayInfo.setContentView(R.layout.overlay_view);
    overlayInfo.show();

    mOverLayImage = (ImageView) overlayInfo.findViewById(R.id.over_lay_image);
    mOverLayImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {                
            overlayInfo.cancel();
        }
    });        
}
}
```

Also check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31198016/2556660) and [this](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView).

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: This should be a comment !!

Comment: @Piyush Thanks for the information. i have already commented the same and no response. So i just mentioned the same as the answer.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16082810)

Comment: @ProkashSarkar i have updated the answer with basics.

Comment: No 3rd party libraries please.

Answer (score 0):

You can check window size and according to that you can set width and height programmatically.

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
```

You can also get size in fragment also:

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
```

Comment: This doesn't explain how to cover anything.